# Cleaned the disk by mistake using diskpart. Is it possbile to recover the data stored in the particular partition?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

So I had this particular partition in which there were important files
and I was trying to install Windows on the disk but was not able to because it had GPT partition system and by mistake I ran the 'clean' which cleared all the partitions on the disk.

I then converted into MBR type, made new partitions, and installed Windows.
But of course the files were lost.

Is it possible to recover those files now?
What to do?

Comment: Well, the first thing you **always** need to do when you make data inaccessible by normal means is: **stop using the computer** (or more accurately, stop using that drive). Most of the data is still there, and most of it is very likely recoverable, but every second you are using that drive you make recovery more difficult. The second thing you need to do is tell us: do you have any backup? (I guess not.) Because restoring from your most recent backup is *far* easier, and *far* more likely to get you good results, than running data recovery software which tries to put the pieces back together.

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/841045/recover-or-recreate-partition-after-diskpart-clean